# Selecting three slides out of five slides randomly with a script and displaying it and hiding the two slides that were not selected

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have the following html and javascript code that has a slider with five slides
I need three slides out of five to be randomly selected every time the page is loaded, and the two slides that are not selected will be completely hidden.
Thank you for telling me where is the problem with my code?

I tried the following code, but all five slides show that every time the page is loaded, three of the slides randomly have content and two are empty.
I need those two blank slides not to be displayed

```js
const slogans = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.slogan'));
const nonEmptySlogans = slogans.filter(slogan => slogan.innerHTML.trim() !== '');

if (nonEmptySlogans.length >= 3) {
  const selectedSlogans = [];

  while (selectedSlogans.length < 3) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * nonEmptySlogans.length);
    const randomSlogan = nonEmptySlogans.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0];
    selectedSlogans.push(randomSlogan);
    randomSlogan.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
'use strict'
var testim = document.getElementById("testim"),
  testimDots = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("testim-dots").children),
  testimContent = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("testim-content").children),
  testimLeftArrow = document.getElementById("left-arrow"),
  testimRightArrow = document.getElementById("right-arrow"),
  testimSpeed = 4500,
  currentSlide = 0,
  currentActive = 0,
  testimTimer,
  touchStartPos,
  touchEndPos,
  touchPosDiff,
  ignoreTouch = 30;;

window.onload = function() {

  // Testim Script
  function playSlide(slide) {
    for (var k = 0; k < testimDots.length; k++) {
      testimContent[k].classList.remove("active");
      testimContent[k].classList.remove("inactive");
      testimDots[k].classList.remove("active");
    }

    if (slide < 0) {
      slide = currentSlide = testimContent.length - 1;
    }

    if (slide > testimContent.length - 1) {
      slide = currentSlide = 0;
    }

    if (currentActive != currentSlide) {
      testimContent[currentActive].classList.add("inactive");
    }
    testimContent[slide].classList.add("active");
    testimDots[slide].classList.add("active");

    currentActive = currentSlide;

    clearTimeout(testimTimer);
    testimTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      playSlide(currentSlide += 1);
    }, testimSpeed)
  }

  testimLeftArrow.addEventListener("click", function() {
    playSlide(currentSlide -= 1);
  })

  testimRightArrow.addEventListener("click", function() {
    playSlide(currentSlide += 1);
  })

  for (var l = 0; l < testimDots.length; l++) {
    testimDots[l].addEventListener("click", function() {
      playSlide(currentSlide = testimDots.indexOf(this));
    })
  }

  playSlide(currentSlide);

  // keyboard shortcuts
  document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 37:
        testimLeftArrow.click();
        break;

      case 39:
        testimRightArrow.click();
        break;

      case 39:
        testimRightArrow.click();
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  })

  testim.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
    touchStartPos = e.changedTouches[0].clientX;
  })

  testim.addEventListener("touchend", function(e) {
    touchEndPos = e.changedTouches[0].clientX;

    touchPosDiff = touchStartPos - touchEndPos;

    console.log(touchPosDiff);
    console.log(touchStartPos);
    console.log(touchEndPos);


    if (touchPosDiff > 0 + ignoreTouch) {
      testimLeftArrow.click();
    } else if (touchPosDiff < 0 - ignoreTouch) {
      testimRightArrow.click();
    } else {
      return;
    }

  })
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section id="testim" class="testim">
    <div class="testim-cover">
      <div class="wrap">

        <span id="right-arrow" class="arrow right fa fa-chevron-right"></span>
        <span id="left-arrow" class="arrow left fa fa-chevron-left "></span>
        <ul id="testim-dots" class="dots">
          <li class="dot active"></li>
          <!--
                    -->
          <li class="dot"></li>
          <!--
                    -->
          <li class="dot"></li>
          <!--
                    -->
          <li class="dot"></li>
          <!--
                    -->
          <li class="dot"></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="testim-content" class="cont">

          <div class="slogan">
            <p>"How does visual identity design help business/product value grow?"</p>
            <h2>MINE</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="slogan">
            <p>"How can we analyze ourselves, audience, competitors, and market and help business progress/grow?"</p>
            <h2>MINE</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="slogan">
            <p>"How can I differentiate my business from others?"</p>
            <h2>MINE</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="slogan">
            <p>"What is the best and latest business model and plan for me?"</p>
            <h2>MINE</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="slogan">
            <p>"How will innovative targeting be achieved at each stage of business?"</p>
            <h2>MINE</h2>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: You should add `visibility: hidden;` or `display: none;` to your `.inactive` CSS definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this set.

```js
const getRandomNumber = count => Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
const randomNumbers = (len, count) => {
  const numbers = new Set();
  while (numbers.size < len) numbers.add(getRandomNumber(count));
  return [...numbers];
};

const slogans = [...document.querySelectorAll('.slogan')];
const nonEmptySlogans = slogans.filter(slogan => slogan.textContent.trim() !== '');

if (nonEmptySlogans.length >= 3) {
  const showList = randomNumbers(3, nonEmptySlogans); // get 3 of how many found
  slogans.forEach((slogan,i) => slogan.classList.toggle("show",showList.contains(i))
}
```

using this CSS

```css
.slogan { display: none }
.slogan.show { display: block }
```